# (C++) Matrix multiplication in a templated Matrix class

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I came across a problem with my matrix class and i can't find a solution.

```
Matrix = ROWSxCOLUMNS

Let A be a 3x4 matrix
Let B be a 4x5 matrix
```

The operation `AxB` (which is defined only if the columns of A match the rows of B) leads to a `3x5 matrix`.
I wanted to create a templated class that does just that.

```
Matrix<int,3,4> A;
Matrix<int,4,5> B;
Matrix<int,3,5> matrix = A*B;
```

My code:

```
    template <class T, unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLUMNS>
    class Matrix {
      public:

        /* blabla */

        const Matrix<T, ROWS, /* ? */ >&
          operator*(const Matrix<T, COLUMNS, /* ? */ >& matrix) const
        {
          /* multiplication */
        }

        /* blabla */
    };
```

I don't know what to insert in the `/* ? */` sections.
Is there a way to let the compiler accept any unsigned integer value? Should i rewrite the code in a different way?

Note: I'm creating this class for academic purposes, i don't care if there are already libraries that do this.

Comment: May i propose to Google for "matrix template C++"? - http://www.drdobbs.com/a-c-matrix-template-class/184403323?pgno=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a template member function with an integer template parameter:

```
template<class T, unsigned int ROWS, unsigned int COLUMNS>
class Matrix {
public:
    ... 
    template<unsigned int N>
    Matrix<T, ROWS, N>
    operator*(const Matrix<T, COLUMNS, N>& matrix) const
    {
          /* multiplication */
    }
    ...
};
```

Also, do not return the value by reference.

Comment: How do i specify that template parameter in the multiplication? In my example, Matrix<int,3,5> matrix = A*B; will this work without specifying N?

Comment: Yes, it will work without specifying N. The compiler figures out what N is by looking at the type of B. (It is called template argument deduction.)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [this Example](https://bitbucket.org/hpsfo/hpsfo.bitbucket.org/src/563a3c12cba13ef6b5bb2b9aad6f76687b7d4e0c/code/src/sfo_matrix.h?at=master#cl-1845) but instead of doing the triple loop (very inefficient) I delegate to Intel MKL `dgemm`.

Note also using the `operator*()` for a matrix type is a bad idea because you need to return the result by value, unless you are sure that you have a compiler with enabled Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO) and tested it works. Namely you don't want to return a matrix by value and incur into a very expensive matrix copying. This is why in my implementation I choose to define a method `multiply` instead of overloading the `operator*()`

An efficient alternative to the `operator*()` would be to define the `operator*=()` so you use it like this, and the result of the multiplication is stored into A directly:

```
A *= B; // or A = A*B
```

Comment: Very interesting! After reasoning a while i think i will do as you did. The multiply method seems a better option for me too. Thank you.